# CSS - parent disappears when child is fixed (even though its height is set)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having issues when creating my sticky header - it basically disappears when I set its child's position to 'fixed'. 
This is my current scenario:

- header: it's a parent with two children ('logo-container', which is static,
  and 'nav' which is relative-positioned)
- the 'logo-container' display property is set to 'none' when scrolling
- the 'nav' position is set to 'fixed' when scrolling
- using jquery I give the header the same height as my nav, so that the rest of the content doesn't jump when nav is set to fixed - but it does and I have no idea why

  - when I check firebug, it shows that my header is '60px' tall (same height as 'nav') so the height is being applied, but I can see that the header is missing, as if its height was set to 0

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
        <header class="row">
            <div id="logo-container" class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1">
                <img src="https//:placehold.it/150x30" alt="my img" id="logo"/>
            </div>
            <nav class="col-lg-12 no-padding">
                <ul id="nav-list" class="col-lg-12">
                    <li>Link 0</li>
                    <li>link 1</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="main-container" class="row">
            <div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1 no-padding">
                // body
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background: green;
}

#logo-container {
    padding: 20px 15px 20px 0px;
}

nav {
    background: red;    
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
}
nav.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
#nav-list {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 10% 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#main-container { /* jumps when 'nav' is fixed */
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 30px 0;  
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    var mainContainer = $('#main-container');
    var nav = $('nav');
    var navHeight = nav.outerHeight();
    var navPos = nav.offset().top;
    var logoContainer = $('#logo-container');

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navPos) {
            $('header').height(navHeight); // set its height so that it stays in place, even with a fixed-positioned child
            nav.addClass('fixed');

        }
        else {
            logoContainer.show();
            nav.removeClass('fixed');
            $('header').removeAttr('style');
        }
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed=  The element is positioned relative to the browser window. If that helps than your welcome.

Comment: Yes, I know. And when an element is fixed, it is 'ignored' by other elements, which causes that jumping effect when we use sticky headers. However, I have a 'placeholder' (the header itself, which is static and has a height set), so the jumping effect shouldn't happen.